# Windows Server 2012 IIS Issues

Tags: html, mysql, iis, phpmyadmin

Let me first say I soley beleive IIS is usless because I have never gotten it to work ever, no matter what I do it never lets me access the website. 
Before I start let me establish I have no choice but to use IIS in this instance and I really need this to work. 


Let me also establish the following:
**Yes I have tried turning it off and on again**

***There is 0 (NONE) firewall on this machine, and yes the server is entirely updated***

My question is, whenever I try to create a website, for example the port im launching a server on is on port 3606.

I am attempting to have my website come up on port 3606, and direct me into a folder that is located at c:\mysqlservices

Now! Inside this folder is phpmyadmin source files, and in a desperate attempt to get this to work I have made the permissions to where EVERYONE, IUSR and IIS_USR all have full read write and nuking permisisons to this directory, its files, and all of its subdirectories.

Now, When I go to this address, for example, panel.archservers.com:3606,
All I get is the issue "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."

Thank you in advance for the help, all I need is to get this IIS server to actually work, because as it is, I cannot do anything with this IIS server..

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: And i added IIS_IUSRS, still nothing, it refuses to let me access it same forbidden error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://sanuja.com/blog/resolving-iis-403-forbidden-access-is-denied) suggest to add "IIS_IUSRS" user, which is not the same as "IIS_USR".

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install the PHP core, then reset my permissions back to just iis_usrs.
It worked great

Answer (score 0):

you are entering a wrong context...give a correct context of your application it will open that page..

Ex:

www.example.com - Forbidden Error

www.example.com/ex.jsp - Displays the respected page

Also check proper permissions are supplied or not to the directories